# I am trying to fetch a pdf document from Companies House API

Tags: api, coldfusion

I am trying to fetch a pdf document from API using ColdFusion and I receive this error:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code> <Message>Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified</Message><ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName> <ArgumentValue>#key#</ArgumentValue> <RequestId>Some requestid</RequestId> <HostId>some host id</HostId>`

400 Bad Request

Here is my code:

```
<cfset urlD="https://document-api.company-information.service.gov.uk/document/#documentID#/content">
<cfhttp urlD="#Url#" method="GET" result="takeDoc" resolveurl="Yes" timeout="999">
   <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Accept" value="application/pdf">
   <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="content-length" value=93295 />
   <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Authorization" value="#key#"/>  
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#takeDoc#">

Any ideas how to solve this final step?
```

Comment: Should your `Authorization` key name be `X-Amz-Algorithm` instead? i.e. `<cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="#key#"/>`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've tried that too and it gives me the error 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: So that would be progress then.

Comment: X-Amz-Algorithm instead? i.e. <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="#key#"/> is not a working 

Comment: I've solved this issue. My authorization key was sent to the amazon server when companies house was forwarding my API request. Amz allows only one mechanism of authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I appears you are transmitting the value #key# as your Authorization instead of the value for the variable key. try putting cfoutput tags around your cfhttp tags.